# formating problem :TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

i run this formating code  `print("%15s%.2f"%((heights[j])),end="")` but i have this error what is the wrong here ??

`TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: You have 2 placeholders and only one given variable. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

What does your `heights` looks like?

Here is a working example

```
heights = [("test",3.14)]
print("%15s%.2f"%((heights[0])),end="")
```

So `heights` must be a list of tuples or lists  with 2 elements.

Comment: height = (float(line[1]))

Answer (score 0):

the first `%` formats the first value into the string and the second `%` formats the second value. The problem is you only have one value to format into the string (unless `heights[j]` is a `list` or `tuple`.

if you want `heights[j` to be formatted in both places, i suggest doing something like this:

```
print("{0}15s{0}.2f".format(heights[j]), end="")
```

this will replace every `{0}` in the string with the first argument passed to `format()`

Comment: but i need to round it i used before  round() but the last decimal if its zero  did not show 
eg. (1.70=1.7)

Comment: @juua if you know that the height is always one number (1.7/1.6/1.9 and not 12.5/20.2) you can cast you float to a string and check its length. if the length is 2, append a '0' to the end and then print is